# No puedo cortar cadena por metacaracter )

Tags: python, string, split

muchas gracias de antemano.
Estoy formateando una cadena, para que sirva como ruta de linux , para ello tengo que cortarla y unirla utilizando \ para escapar los espacios, lo cual hace correctamente. El problema es cuando hay parentesis y hay que "escaparlos" , en el ejemplo deberia de quedar \(2020\).Pero tengo problemas con el metacaracter ")" simplemente me lo coge como si fuera "(" lo he intentado de mil maneras pero no lo consigo. Pongo el ejemplo:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Jan 13 21:22:18 2021
Ejemplo para foro
@author: jm
"""

cadena="/mnt/ext4/torrents/incoming/TRATAMIENTO/Xx Xxxxxx (2020) [BluRay 720p X264 MKV][AC3 5.1 Castellano]"


def prepararPath2(cadena):
     
     cadenaSplit=cadena.split()
     for palabra in cadenaSplit:
         cadenaFinal='\ '.join(cadenaSplit)
         
     print("La cadena modificada  es "+ cadenaFinal+"\n")
     
     #cadenaFinal=cadenaFinal.split("(2020)")
     cadenaFinal=cadenaFinal.split("(")
     
     print("cadena cortada con (")
     print(cadenaFinal)
     print("\n")
     
     for palabra in cadenaFinal:
         
         cadenaFinal2='\('.join(cadenaFinal)
         # cadenaFinal2='\(\)'.join(cadenaFinal)
     print (cadenaFinal2)

     
    #Volvemos a cortar para el otro parentesis
     print("cadena cortada con )")
     cadenaFinal2.split(")")
     
     print(cadenaFinal)
     print("\n")
     
     for palabra in cadenaFinal2:
         
         cadenaFinal3='\)'.join(cadenaFinal)
     
                                 
     return cadenaFinal3
 
    
 
print(prepararPath2(cadena))
print( ord(")")) #devuelve el carcter ascii 41
print( ord("(")) #devuelve el carcter ascii 40
```

He probado utilizando ascii y tampoco, el programa devuelve:

```
La cadena modificada  es /mnt/ext4/torrents/incoming/TRATAMIENTO/Xx\ Xxxxxx\ (2020)\ [BluRay\ 720p\ X264\ MKV][AC3\ 5.1\ Castellano]

cadena cortada con (
['/mnt/ext4/torrents/incoming/TRATAMIENTO/Xx\\ Xxxxxx\\ ', '2020)\\ [BluRay\\ 720p\\ X264\\ MKV][AC3\\ 5.1\\ Castellano]']


/mnt/ext4/torrents/incoming/TRATAMIENTO/Xx\ Xxxxxx\ \(2020)\ [BluRay\ 720p\ X264\ MKV][AC3\ 5.1\ Castellano]
cadena cortada con )
['/mnt/ext4/torrents/incoming/TRATAMIENTO/Xx\\ Xxxxxx\\ ', '2020)\\ [BluRay\\ 720p\\ X264\\ MKV][AC3\\ 5.1\\ Castellano]']


/mnt/ext4/torrents/incoming/TRATAMIENTO/Xx\ Xxxxxx\ \)2020)\ [BluRay\ 720p\ X264\ MKV][AC3\ 5.1\ Castellano]
41
40
```

Es decir me confunde ")" con "(" lo entiende como un mismo caracter.

Comment: Para que una cadena que contiene espacios y paréntesis pueda ser usada en el shell, basta con entrecomillarla. Los nombres de rutas con espacios o paréntesis no son problema para el sistema de archivos, es el shell el que puede "confundirse" pues usa el espacio como separador de comandos y los paréntesis para crear subprocesos. Pero estos problemas se evitan poniendo entre comillas toda la ruta. Así que en vez de insertar muchos `\` por el medio, te basta insertar un `"` al inicio y otro al final.

Comment: Buenos días, muchas gracias por la respuesta, desconocía lo del entrecomillado de la shell. Veo que funciona si la cadena es simple por ejemplo: Xxxx Xxx (2020), pero si ademas lleva corchetes,etc (como es el caso), da error:  -ash: syntax error: unexpected "(", supongo que habria que utilizar además el entrecomillado simple para los parentesis.Con lo cual se complica casi lo mismo.Se me olvido decir que son comandos que lanzo a traves de una conexion ssh con Paramiko. (commmand_exec).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te faltó asignar el resultado del split, en:

```
#Volvemos a cortar para el otro parentesis
     print("cadena cortada con )")
     cadenaFinal2.split(")")
     
     print(cadenaFinal)
     print("\n")
```

Debería de ser:

```
#Volvemos a cortar para el otro parentesis
     print("cadena cortada con )")
     cadenaFinal=cadenaFinal2.split(")")
     
     print(cadenaFinal)
     print("\n")
```

También podrías usar [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

```
def prepararPath2(cadena):
    cadenaFinal = cadena.replace("(","\(")
    cadenaFinal = cadenaFinal.replace(")","\)")
    
    return cadenaFinal
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto, muchas gracias.